# View Loading.gif image while retrieving data C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, loading, picturebox

On a WinForm application, I have a form that contains a GridView, I am filling the GridView by collecting the data from a database.
I Have a pictureBox that contains a Loading.gif image.
What do i want is to view the PictureBox during retrieving the data from the database.

I tried the bellow code, but it did not work...

> ```
>  private void Generate_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>  {              
>       pictureBox1.Visible = true;      
>       {    
>             Generate_Button.Text = "Done";
>             if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
>                 conn.Open();                
>             radGridView1.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("Account No."));
>             radGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 85;
>             bool DataAvailable = false;
>             if (MainAccNo_TextBox.Text == "" && CurencyNo_TextBox.Text == "")
>             {
>                 if (SeparateBy_DropDownList.Text == "4")
>                 {
>                     for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
>                     {
>                         for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
>                         {
>                             for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++)
>                             {
>                                 for (int l = 0; l <= 9; l++)
>                                 {
>                                     SqlCommand cmd_AccNo = new SqlCommand("Select distinct(AccNo) from JourTrans where AccNo like '" + i + "" + j + "" + k + "" + l + "%'", conn);
>                                     SqlDataReader reader_AccNo = cmd_AccNo.ExecuteReader();      
>                                     radGridView1.Rows.Add(i + "" + j + "" + k + "" + l);
>                                     while (reader_AccNo.Read())
>                                     {
>                                         Accounts.Add(reader_AccNo["AccNo"].ToString());
>                                         radGridView1.Rows.Add(reader_AccNo["AccNo"].ToString());
>                                         DataAvailable = true;
>                                     }
>                                     reader_AccNo.Close();
>                                     if (DataAvailable == true)
>                                     {
>                                         radGridView1.Rows.Add("");
>                                         DataAvailable = false;
>                                     }
>                                     else
>                                       radGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(radGridView1.Rows.Count - 1);
>                                 }
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }  
>             }
>         }                
>      pictureBox1.Visible = false;
>   }
> ```

http://soundfrost.org/ >download youtube videos

Answer (score 2):

Do your retrieving in another thread and use Dispatcher so that you can access your controls from that thread:

```
pictureBox1.Visible = true;   
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
{    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    {                                               
        //Here I am retrieving data from the database       
    } 
    pictureBox1.Visible = false; 
}));
```

Comment: Oh. Then maybe this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303116/system-windows-threading-dispatcher-and-winforms