# Cross-Thread Exception with backgroud worker when adding text to a richtextbox

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to code something that retrieves and parses the HTML of a site. I am successful on that but when I try to put it into a rich textbox using a background worker I get a cross-thread exception.

```
List<string> retuInfo = new List<string>();
foreach (var inf in info)
{
       retuInfo.Add(inf.InnerText);
       richTextBox1.Lines = retuInfo.ToArray();
}
```

I get the exception on `richTextBox1.Lines = retuInfo.ToArray();`

I have looked at several things on "Unsafe threading and safe threading" but none of it really helped as threading is a pretty advanced topic and can throw some hard bugs at you.

Any possible help?

Comment: We've had this a million times here... Invoke is the keyword.

Comment: You can also take a look at [SynchronizationContext](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I) class.

Comment: In which method you are using this code? Write the logic in the ProgressChanged method if you are accessing any UI method and call it using ReportProgress method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update UI control you should call from UI thread instead of you update from `Backgroundworker` thread. To call Ui thread you should use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to call thread UI update on Richtextbox control.

You can take reference here:

[Invoke(Delegate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703698/c-invokedelegate)

or

[Parallel Programming using TPL on WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998459/parallel-programming-using-tpl-on-winforms/15998553#15998553)

Comment: So I am checking out the second link you gave me there and I tried this still getting some errors and its a bit a confusing but am I on the right track?    List<string> retuInfo = new List<string>();
            richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(()richTextBox1.Lines = retuInfo.ToArray());

Comment: Fixed it no error this time except nothings happening now?richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.Lines = retuInfo.ToArray()));

Comment: Aye! It worked sorry I realized I did not put back the foreach thing it's been a long day of everyday things and a long night of coding. I really appreciate this with helping me better understand and learn guys. I really appreciate and honestly wish I could put both for best answer -.-

Comment: Good job John. Glad to see you can resolve it by yourself.

Comment: One more thing can you explain to me how richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.Lines = retuInfo.ToArray()));  worked?I dont understand the "new Action and =>"

Comment: the new Action()=> .. actually is create a new anonymous delegate. Take reference here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: You can take reference at here to learn how to use and get benefit from it instead of using directly delegate syntax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371054/uses-of-action-delegate-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

In your form define a method that will append the lines to the control:

```
public void SetRichTextBoxText(string[] lines)
{
    if(!richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        richTextBox1.Lines = lines;
    }
    else
    {
        var callback = new Action<string[]>(SetRichTextBoxText);
        Invoke(callback, lines);
    }
}
```

In your background worker call the method like this:

```
form.SetRichTextBoxText(info.Select(inf => inf.InnerText).ToArray());
```