# Why did dispatcher BeginInvoke fail where Control BeginInvoke succeed in C# Windows Forms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, dispatcher, begininvoke

I originally tried to use the Dispatcher class BeginInvoke method to show a message box on the main UI thread in my C# Windows Forms app.  When I used that method *the message box did not appear*.  I set a breakpoint inside the body of the delegate I passed to BeginInvoke() and it was *never* hit.  I tried using both an *Action* delegate and a *MethodInvoker* delegate.  No luck in either case.

When I used the BeginInvoke method belonging to the Form object it *worked fine*.  Why did the Dispatch version fail silently (no exceptions or error messages)?  Below are the two different versions.

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

// THIS FAILED. CONTEXT: Executing on worker thread.
MethodInvoker theMethod = new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
    string msg = "Show this  message on the main UI thread.";
    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Message");
});

dispatcher.BeginInvoke(theMethod);

this.BeginInvoke(theMethod);

// ---------------------------------------------------

// THIS WORKED. CONTEXT: Executing on worker thread.
MethodInvoker theMethod = new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
    string msg = "Show this  message on the main UI thread.";
    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Message");
});

// "this" is a Form object.
this.BeginInvoke(theMethod);
```

Comment: Seems like this page contains an example of how to use `Dispatcher` with winforms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303116/system-windows-threading-dispatcher-and-winforms

Comment: I tried your `dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);` code and it worked fine in .NET4.

Comment: @Loathing Thanks for testing.  I (more than) triple-checked during testing and I can assure you that for me it absolutely didn't work.  So now we have a truly strange situation apparently.

Comment: @RobertOschler: There's already a good answer here, but as a side note: You shouldn't be using either of the `BeginInvoke` methods. To report progress, use `IProgress<T>`. To update the UI with results, use `await`. To dynamically update the UI from an asynchronous stream, use Rx's `ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext)`. These newer ways decouple your logic from your UI and are unit testable.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks Stephen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your comments correctly, you are calling `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from a non-UI thread.  This is not how this is meant to be used.

As the documentation for [Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms593902(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Gets the Dispatcher ***for the thread currently executing*** and creates a new Dispatcher if one is not already ***associated with the thread***.

To get a valid dispatcher instance, you need to call `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from the UI thread.

Also, because the documentation says that it will automatically create a dispatcher if one does not exist for the current thread, this is what explains the silent failure.  You are getting a dispatcher instance, but it isn't associated to the UI thread in any way, so it isn't actually dispatching anything to the UI thread.

(Removing this, because in my tests, I get null even when I shouldn't, so it doesn't prove much it seems.  The rest of the information is accurate though)
<del>The documentation also adds:</del>

<del>This is not the case with the `FromThread` method. `FromThread` will return `null` if there is not a dispatcher associated with the specified thread.</del>

<del>So to confirm that you are indeed getting an auto-created (invalid) dispatcher, try getting the dispatcher from [Dispatcher.FromThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591591(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. My guess is that you will get `null`.</del>

If you want to call `dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to force execution of a method on the UI thread from a worker thread, you need to call `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from the UI thread and save that to a variable.  You can then pass that dispatcher reference variable to the worker thread, and call `BeginInvoke` on that.

```
// capture and save dispatcher from UI thread
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

// then you can do this from your worker thread:
dispatcher.BeginInvoke(theMethod);
```

Alternatively, use `this.BeginInvoke` like you are doing already.

Or better yet, you can try using tasks combined with the new `async-await` keywords for this sort of thing.

**EDIT**

For completeness, I should explain why `Control.BeginInvoke` does work correctly.

As the documentation for [Control.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on.

And later it also adds:

> You can call this method from any thread.

The point is that, when you call `Control.BeginInvoke`, it doesn't use the current thread to determine how to execute the delegate.  It remembers which thread the control was created on (the UI thread), and makes sure to execute the delegate on that thread.

So, as long as your control is created on the UI thread (as it should), then `BeginInvoke` works from any thread.  This is actually quite similar to the `Dispatcher` in that, as long as you obtain the `Dispatcher` instance from the UI thread first, then you can call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` from any thread as well.